# Scraping text with subscripts with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

all! I'm working on my first web scraper ever, which grabs author names, URLs, and paper names from PMC, when given a "CitedBy" page [like this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2593677/citedby/?page=0)

My program works fine for getting the author names and the URL's, however I can only get some of the paper titles, which I suspect is due to subscripts and superscripts.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2593677/citedby/?page=0'
    req = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml") #soup object

    titles_list = []

    for items in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'title'}):
        title = items.string
        if title is None:
            title = ("UHOH") #Problems with some titles
        #print(title)
        titles_list.append(title)
```

When I run this part of my code, my scraper gives me these results:

1. Finding and Comparing Syntenic Regions among Arabidopsis and the Outgroups Papaya, Poplar, and Grape: CoGe with Rosids
2. UHOH
3. Comprehensive Comparative Genomic and Transcriptomic Analyses of the Legume Genes Controlling the Nodulation Process
4. UHOH
5. Dosage Sensitivity of RPL9 and Concerted Evolution of Ribosomal Protein Genes in Plants

And so on for the whole page...

Some papers on this page that I get "UHOH" for are:

- Comparative cell-specific transcriptomics reveals differentiation of C4 photosynthesis pathways in switchgrass and other C4 lineages
- The genome sequence of the outbreeding globe artichoke constructed de novo incorporating a phase-aware low-pass sequencing strategy of F1 progeny
- Cross-Family Translational Genomics of Abiotic Stress-Responsive Genes between Arabidopsis and Medicago truncatula

The first two I've listed here I believe are problematic because of "C4" and "F1" are actually "C subscript 4" and "F subscript 1". For the third one, "Medicago truncatula" is in an "em" HTML tag, so I suspect that this is why my scraper cannot scrape it.

The only alternative solution I've thought of is making my "soup.findAll" more specific, but that didn't end up helping me. I tried:

```
for items in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'title'}):
        title = items.string
        if title is None:
            for other in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'view'}):
                title = other.string
```

But sadly, this didn't work... So I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. Does anybody know how to handle special cases like these? Thank you so much!

Comment: Since you're using the `lxml` parser, shouldn't you be able to just use [`node.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) on the `div.title > a` nodes? That should behave the same for your simple cases, and handle complex cases with nested elements gracefully.

Comment: Looks like for BeautifulSoup that would be [`node.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) - but the principle is the same.

Comment: @LukasGraf You solved my problem!!! Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome - I'm on the run so I just dropped a couple pointers, but If you want to expand that into a full answer and self-accept, I'll be happy to upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LukasGraf, I have the answer!

Since I'm using the BeautifulSoup, I can use [node.get_text()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text). It works different from the plain, ".string" because it also returns all the text beneath a tag, which was the case for the subscripts and "em" HTML marked text.